# It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have been using Jupyter Notebook for my machine learning project. Before scikit-learn was working fine but eventually I installed `pip install imblearn` and `pip install -U imbalanced-learn` after which scikit-learn stopped working and I was getting the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Input: from sklearn.utils import resample




ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py in <module>
     43 try:
---> 44     from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
     45 except ImportError as e:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ammarkamran/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Users/ammarkamran/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../.dylibs/libomp.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/ammarkamran/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../.dylibs/libomp.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-459293077533> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.utils import resample

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in <module>
     79     # it and importing it first would fail if the OpenMP dll cannot be found.
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
---> 81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
     82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py in <module>
     44     from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
     45 except ImportError as e:
---> 46     raise_build_error(e)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py in raise_build_error(e)
     39 to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
     40 `make` in the source directory.
---> 41 %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg))
     42 
     43 try:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ammarkamran/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Users/ammarkamran/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../.dylibs/libomp.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/ammarkamran/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../.dylibs/libomp.dylib
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /Users/ammarkamran/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build:
__init__.py               __pycache__               setup.py
_check_build.cpython-37m-darwin.so
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

Looking at other sources online and questions at Stack Overflow I found out that it could be solved by installing scikit-learn again so I tried:

```
pip install scikit-learn

Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (0.14.1)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Also, I tried:

```
conda install scikit-learn

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.


Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Unfortunately, even after installing and restarting, I got the same error. I am using this on my Macbook and like I said I was easily able to import sklearn before, the problem only started after I installed imblearn. Additionally, after restarting Anaconda Navigator, it asked to update, after clicking yes nothing really happened. I am not sure if that is related, although this was the first time I was asked to update Anaconda.

Edited part - So I uninstalled Jupyter Notebook and reinstalled it. This fixed my problem for sklearn. However, I am still not sure how to install 'imlearn' which was my original problem. As requested below is my list of packages:

```
# packages in environment at /Users/ammarkamran/opt/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda                  2020.02                  py37_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0  
applaunchservices         0.2.1                      py_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0  
appscript                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
argh                      0.26.2                   py37_0  
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0  
astroid                   2.3.3                    py37_0  
astropy                   4.0              py37h1de35cc_0  
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1  
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0  
autopep8                  1.4.4                      py_0  
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
backports                 1.0                        py_2  
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2  
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1  
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1  
beautifulsoup4            4.8.2                    py37_0  
bitarray                  1.2.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0  
blosc                     1.16.3               hd9629dc_0  
bokeh                     1.4.0                    py37_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0  
bottleneck                1.3.2            py37h776bbcc_0  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0  
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0  
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0  
cffi                      1.14.0           py37hb5b8e2f_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003  
click                     7.0                      py37_0  
cloudpickle               1.3.0                      py_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1  
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0  
conda                     4.8.2                    py37_0  
conda-build               3.18.11                  py37_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1  
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0  
cryptography              2.8              py37ha12b0ac_0  
curl                      7.68.0               ha441bb4_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
cython                    0.29.15          py37h0a44026_0  
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py37h1de35cc_0  
dask                      2.11.0                     py_0  
dask-core                 2.11.0                     py_0  
dbus                      1.13.12              h90a0687_0  
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
diff-match-patch          20181111                   py_0  
distributed               2.11.0                   py37_0  
docutils                  0.16                     py37_0  
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0  
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0  
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
flake8                    3.7.9                    py37_0  
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0  
fsspec                    0.6.2                      py_0  
future                    0.18.2                   py37_0  
fuzzywuzzy                0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3  
gevent                    1.4.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
glib                      2.63.1               hd977a24_0  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h6ef4df4_2  
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h1de35cc_0  
h5py                      2.10.0           py37h3134771_0  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hfa1e0ec_0  
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0  
hypothesis                5.5.4                      py_0  
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1  
idna                      2.8                      py37_0  
imageio                   2.6.1                    py37_0  
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0  
importlib_metadata        1.5.0                    py37_0  
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233  
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_0  
ipykernel                 5.1.4            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.12.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0  
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0  
jedi                      0.14.1                   py37_0  
jinja2                    2.11.1                     py_0  
joblib                    0.14.1                     py_0  
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
json5                     0.9.1                      py_0  
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0  
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0  
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0  
jupyterlab                1.2.6              pyhf63ae98_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0  
keyring                   21.1.0                   py37_0  
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37h0a44026_0  
krb5                      1.17.1               hddcf347_0  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5  
libcurl                   7.68.0               h051b688_0  
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7  
liblief                   0.9.0                h2a1bed3_2  
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0  
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h0a44026_0  
libssh2                   1.9.0                ha12b0ac_1  
libtiff                   4.1.0                hcb84e12_0  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hf6e021a_1  
libxslt                   1.1.33               h33a18ac_0  
llvm-openmp               4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
llvmlite                  0.31.0           py37h1341992_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1  
lxml                      4.5.0            py37hef8c89e_0  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
matplotlib                3.1.3                    py37_0  
matplotlib-base           3.1.3            py37h9aa3819_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0  
mkl                       2019.4                      233  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hfbe908c_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h5e564d8_0  
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37ha771720_0  
mock                      4.0.1                      py_0  
more-itertools            8.2.0                      py_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                h3018a27_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0  
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37h04f5b5a_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0  
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0  
nbformat                  5.0.4                      py_0  
ncurses                   6.2                  h0a44026_0  
networkx                  2.4                        py_0  
nltk                      3.4.5                    py37_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2  
notebook                  6.0.3                    py37_0  
numba                     0.48.0           py37h6c726b0_0  
numexpr                   2.7.1            py37hce01a72_0  
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h7241aed_0  
numpy-base                1.18.1           py37h6575580_1  
numpydoc                  0.9.2                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
openpyxl                  3.0.3                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1d               h1de35cc_4  
packaging                 20.1                       py_0  
pandas                    1.0.1            py37h6c726b0_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0  
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0  
path                      13.1.0                   py37_0  
path.py                   12.4.0                        0  
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_0  
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pcre                      8.43                 h0a44026_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0  
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py37_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pillow                    7.0.0            py37h4655f20_0  
pip                       20.0.2                   py37_1  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0  
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0  
ply                       3.11                     py37_0  
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            3.0.3                      py_0  
psutil                    5.6.7            py37h1de35cc_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0  
py                        1.8.1                      py_0  
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37h1413db1_2  
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h1de35cc_9  
pycurl                    7.43.0.5         py37ha12b0ac_0  
pydocstyle                4.0.1                      py_0  
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0  
pygments                  2.5.2                      py_0  
pylint                    2.4.4                    py37_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.30           py37h0a44026_0  
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.6                      py_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2  
pyrsistent                0.15.7           py37h1de35cc_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0  
pytables                  3.6.1            py37h5bccee9_0  
pytest                    5.3.5                    py37_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.8.0                      py_0  
pytest-astropy-header     0.1.2                      py_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.5.0                      py_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.4.0                      py_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.6                h359304d_2  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.4                      py_0  
python-language-server    0.31.7                   py37_0  
python-levenshtein        0.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13  
python.app                2                       py37_10  
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0  
pywavelets                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
pyyaml                    5.3              py37h1de35cc_0  
pyzmq                     18.1.1           py37h0a44026_0  
qdarkstyle                2.8                        py_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1  
qtawesome                 0.6.1                      py_0  
qtconsole                 4.6.0                      py_1  
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0  
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_1  
ripgrep                   11.0.2               he32d670_0  
rope                      0.16.0                     py_0  
rtree                     0.9.3                    py37_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37h1de35cc_0  
scikit-image              0.16.2           py37h6c726b0_0  
scikit-learn              0.22.1           py37h27c97d8_0  
scipy                     1.4.1            py37h9fa6033_0  
seaborn                   0.10.0                     py_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0  
setuptools                46.0.0                   py37_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0  
six                       1.14.0                   py37_0  
snappy                    1.1.7                he62c110_3  
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0  
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0  
soupsieve                 1.9.5                    py37_0  
sphinx                    2.4.0                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.0                      py_0  
spyder                    4.0.1                    py37_0  
spyder-kernels            1.8.1                    py37_0  
sqlalchemy                1.3.13           py37h1de35cc_0  
sqlite                    3.31.1               ha441bb4_0  
statsmodels               0.11.0           py37h1de35cc_0  
sympy                     1.5.1                    py37_0  
tbb                       2020.0               h04f5b5a_0  
tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0  
terminado                 0.8.3                    py37_0  
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0  
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0  
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h1de35cc_3  
tqdm                      4.42.1                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0  
ujson                     1.35             py37h1de35cc_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h1de35cc_0  
urllib3                   1.25.8                   py37_0  
watchdog                  0.10.2           py37h1de35cc_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.8                      py_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  1.0.0                      py_0  
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0  
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37h1de35cc_0  
wurlitzer                 2.0.0                    py37_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0  
xlsxwriter                1.2.7                      py_0  
xlwings                   0.17.1                   py37_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0  
xmltodict                 0.12.0                     py_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
yapf                      0.28.0                     py_0  
zeromq                    4.3.1                h0a44026_3  
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      2.2.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

This time I tried `conda install imblearn` but now I get the error below:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - imblearn

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.



Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Comment: Can you share the list of packages in the Conda environment? Using pip and Conda together requires extra care.

Comment: @AMC I just editied my answer above for you.

Comment: @AmmarKamran I got same error when install sckit-learn 0.24.0 (python 3.6, macOS 10.13)

Comment: @AmmarKamranThere is an issue in scikit-learn related to this question https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19063

Comment: @ Vu Anh I uninstalled and reinstalled Jupyter notebook and it fixed the issue for scikit-learn but still the imblearn library does not seem to work.

Comment: @VuAnh So downgrade for now - thanks for the tip-off!

Comment: @AmmarKamran What OS and OS version?

Answer (score 9):

New builds seems to be build on OS X>10.15 (.dylibs/libomp.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
This problem may happen on lower version Mac OS (I have 10.13.6)

Either upgrade your mac or use a lower version scikit-image (0.17.2 or 0.17.1)

```
pip install -U scikit-image==0.17.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```