# I can import scikit-learn, but I can't use it

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

Whenever I try to run a program, where the first 8 rows are

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import keras
import sklearn
from math import sqrt
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

I get the response `It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.`

However running it manually (one-by-one) it seemingly works

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
>>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot
>>> import pandas
>>> import numpy
>>> import keras
2021-05-28 12:38:06.355731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
>>> exit()
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I tried reinstalling every package already (also on different versions)

Edit: I have missed to add the info, that this is running on a Jetson Nano, so the OS is Linux and the compiler is the default (the program is run through SSH). When using `python3 -VV` it responds `Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) [GCC 8.4.0]` also I'm not using a virtual environment nor do I use other package managers than pip3. Sci-kit learn has been installed using the command `sudo pip3 install scikit-learn`

The install logs:

```
sudo pip3 install scikit-learn  Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting scikit-learn
  Downloading scikit_learn-0.24.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (24.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 24.0 MB 20.5 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in /home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.5.4)
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
Successfully installed scikit-learn-0.24.2
```

The full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../../scikit_learn.libs/libgomp-d22c30c5.so.1.0.0: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LSTMMVMSTSF.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise_build_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 41, in raise_build_error
    %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg))
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../../scikit_learn.libs/libgomp-d22c30c5.so.1.0.0: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/__check_build:
__init__.py               _check_build.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so__pycache__
setup.py
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

Comment: Please, give more information about your system. What is your OS? Are you using a virtual environment or some package manager other than pip? How are you installing the scikit-learn package? Post the logging you get from installing the package.

Comment: @DiegoPalacios I have edited the question, thanks for making me notice

Comment: What's the full error when you run your script and are you running it from somewhere that might have a name collision with sklearn?

Comment: @CJR I have updated the question with the full error message. It shouldn't have any collisions. It's run on the Desktop of the machine and inside the folder, no other file has anything related to sklearn in its name, or even its contents

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14884

Comment: @CJR Thank you so much! That link helped me figure it out. The problem really was just the order of imports. Now I changed it to import sklearn first and it works. If you post it as answer, I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems to be relevant:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66601542/4352317

"New builds seems to be build on OS X>10.15 (.dylibs/libomp.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15) This problem may happen on lower version Mac OS (I have 10.13.6)

Either upgrade your mac or use a lower version scikit-image (0.17.2 or 0.17.1)"

```
pip install -U scikit-image==0.17.2
```

Comment: I've updated the question; this is run on a Jetson Nano, so the OS is Linux