# How do I determine what OS a package was built on?

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, pip

I am having an issue with a package in pip, the version I installed is built on a higher version of MacOS than I am on and I need to downgrade to a previous version. (My problem is similar to [this one which Gorkem answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431999/it-seems-that-scikit-learn-has-not-been-built-correctly). Gorkem mentions the last version of a package which is compatible with MacOS 10.13, and I don't know how he determined this.

What steps can I take to determine which package would be compatible? I've tried `pip show [package]` and I've tried searching the github repository for any mention of build details. I would like to avoid trial-and-error installing previous versions until one is compatible.

I don't think it's relevant to my general question, but I specifically am on MacOS 10.13.6 trying to install tensorflow-text.

Comment: What package is causing the problem?

Comment: At the bottom of my post, as I said, it is tensorflow-text. But I am not looking for a specific solution for that package. I am curious about general steps and ways to determine this. If there are any....