# Cannot Import scikit-learn due to built incorrectly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, miniconda

I am using miniconda3 to create a virtual environment in linux aarch64 architecture.
I install scikit-learn using the pip install scikit-learn. But when I import librosa in the python, I got the following error.
May I know how can I solve the issue?

```
>>> import librosa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/su/miniconda3/envs/acousticpdev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s                                                                             klearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
ImportError: /home/su/miniconda3/envs/acousticpdev/lib/python3.10/site-packa                                                                             ges/sklearn/__check_build/../../scikit_learn.libs/libgomp-d22c30c5.so.1.0.0: can                                                                             not allocate memory in static TLS block

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/su/miniconda3/envs/acousticpdev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/l                                                                             ibrosa/__init__.py", line 211, in <module>
    from . import decompose
  File "/home/su/miniconda3/envs/acousticpdev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/l                                                                             ibrosa/decompose.py", line 19, in <module>
    import sklearn.decomposition
  File "/home/su/miniconda3/envs/acousticpdev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s                                                                             klearn/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/su/miniconda3/envs/acousticpdev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s                                                                             klearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    raise_build_error(e)
  File "/home/su/miniconda3/envs/acousticpdev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s                                                                             klearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 31, in raise_build_error
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: /home/su/miniconda3/envs/acousticpdev/lib/python3.10/site-packa                                                                             ges/sklearn/__check_build/../../scikit_learn.libs/libgomp-d22c30c5.so.1.0.0: can                                                                             not allocate memory in static TLS block
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /home/su/miniconda3/envs/acousticpdev/lib/python3.10/site-packag                                                                             es/sklearn/__check_build:
__pycache__               __init__.py               setup.py
_check_build.cpython-310-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

This is the package that I install :

```
Package                      Version
---------------------------- ------------
absl-py                      1.2.0
appdirs                      1.4.4
astunparse                   1.6.3
attrs                        22.1.0
audioread                    2.1.9
brotlipy                     0.7.0
cachetools                   5.2.0
certifi                      2022.6.15
cffi                         1.15.0
charset-normalizer           2.0.12
cryptography                 37.0.1
cycler                       0.11.0
decorator                    5.1.1
distlib                      0.3.5
filelock                     3.8.0
flatbuffers                  2.0
fonttools                    4.34.4
fpdf                         1.7.2
gast                         0.5.3
google-auth                  2.10.0
google-auth-oauthlib         0.4.4
google-pasta                 0.2.0
grpcio                       1.42.0
h5py                         3.6.0
idna                         3.3
imageio                      2.21.1
joblib                       1.1.0
jsonschema                   4.9.1
keras                        2.8.0
Keras-Preprocessing          1.1.2
kiwisolver                   1.4.4
kneed                        0.8.1
libclang                     14.0.6
librosa                      0.9.2
llvmlite                     0.39.0
logger                       1.4
Markdown                     3.4.1
MarkupSafe                   2.1.1
matplotlib                   3.5.3
networkx                     2.8.5
numba                        0.56.0
numpy                        1.22.3
oauthlib                     2.1.0
opt-einsum                   3.3.0
packaging                    21.3
pandas                       1.4.3
Pillow                       9.2.0
pip                          21.2.4
platformdirs                 2.5.2
pooch                        1.6.0
protobuf                     3.20.1
pyasn1                       0.4.8
pyasn1-modules               0.2.8
pycparser                    2.21
PyJWT                        1.6.4
pyOpenSSL                    22.0.0
pyparsing                    3.0.9
pyrsistent                   0.18.1
PySocks                      1.7.1
python-dateutil              2.8.2
python-Levenshtein           0.12.2
pytz                         2022.2
PyWavelets                   1.3.0
PyYAML                       6.0
rdp                          0.8
requests                     2.27.1
requests-oauthlib            1.0.0
resampy                      0.4.0
rsa                          4.9
scikit-image                 0.19.3
scikit-learn                 1.1.2
scipy                        1.7.3
seaborn                      0.11.2
setuptools                   61.2.0
six                          1.16.0
SoundFile                    0.10.3.post1
tensorboard                  2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server      0.6.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1
tensorflow                   2.8.2
tensorflow-estimator         2.8.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.26.0
termcolor                    1.1.0
threadpoolctl                3.1.0
tifffile                     2022.8.8
typing_extensions            4.3.0
urllib3                      1.26.9
virtualenv                   20.16.3
watchdog                     2.1.9
Werkzeug                     2.2.2
wheel                        0.37.1
wrapt                        1.13.3
```

Before I creating a virtual environment in miniconda3, I also tested creating an environment using pyenv not in the miniconda using the following steps:

```
1. git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
2. cd ~/.pyenv && /home/su/pyenv/src/configure && make -C src
3. echo 'export PYENV_ROOT= "$HOME/.pyenv"'>>~./bashrc
echo 'command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH='$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~./bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc 
4. source ~/.bashrc
5. pyenv install 
6. pip3 install pipenv
7. mkdir /home/su/project 
8. cd /home/su/project
9. pipenv install
10. pipenv shell
11. export PYTHONPATH=.
```

I don't know whether the issue of scikit-learn cannot import related to the above steps of using pyenv?

When I search other similar question in stackoverflow, I found this one [It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431999/it-seems-that-scikit-learn-has-not-been-built-correctly) . I also tried installing `pip install -U scikit-image==0.17.2`  . However, after immediately finish installing scikit-image and import librosa and sklearn, there is no issue. When I exit the python and import librosa and sklearn again, I got the same scikit-learn not built correctly error.

May I know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you mixing `pip` and `conda` commands? Have you tried making a fresh miniconda environment and installing scikit-learn with `conda install`?

Comment: When I create an environment I use conda ```conda create -n myenv tensorflow python```. Then the rest packages are installed with pip command.

Comment: @FiddleStix, for tensorflow and python packages it is installed from conda and the rest are from pip

Comment: @FiddleStix, my conda cannot install all the above packages due to error about ```ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - python=3.1
```.  But my python version is 3.10.0. I don't know why it gives Resolve PackageNotFound - python=3.1?? Therefore, I use only pip command.

Comment: Ah, I see. If it sometimes works (straight after install) but then doesn't when you restart your terminal then it probably is because of your pyenv/pipenv steps. Depending on whether you think the conda install worked properly or the pipenv one did, I would either remove the extra lines from your .bashrc file or re-activate the pipenv shell in /home/su/project. At the moment, I think your mixing and matching environments.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your issue with a fresh Conda environment, which is what I recommend. My current test is with `conda create --name scikit python==3.10 scikit-learn` and then I would do `conda activate scikit` and `conda install <name>` for all further dependencies that conda supports.

Comment: I notice you have `scikit-learn==1.1.2` in your package list, whereas conda is installing 1.1.1 for me. If you need the lastest, you'd have to use conda-forge: `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn==1.1.2`.

Comment: You definitely want to avoid mixing and matching conda envs with other virtual envs. If you're using conda, try to stick with conda envs, it will make your life easier.

Comment: @Susan, just wondering, did my answer below help at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer to your question is that you need to install your packages from the conda forge. You're using packages that are not all available through the default conda channel (`conda search librosa` yields nothing) but that are indeed all available in the conda-forge channel (`conda search -c conda-forge librosa` lists many versions).

The packages you're trying to install require complex and lengthy compilation with a bunch of dependencies, so I would try hard to avoid doing that.

This worked for me:

```
conda create --name scikit python==3.10
conda activate scikit
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn librosa
python -c "import librosa"
```

A lot of the advanced machine learning modules are published to the conda forge channel quite quickly, whereas the official (default) conda channel takes longer to vet things before including them. I don't know the exact policies of each channel, but https://conda-forge.org/ says it's community driven, so you can expect new contributions to make it there faster.

One last word of advice: it's best to avoid mixing and matching virtual environments. Since you've installed Python itself with conda, you'll find it easier to use just conda environments for everything you do.